# Highlight custom tokens in VS?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way in `Visual Studio` to set tokens like `HACK` to highlight to a specific color like `Todo` does?

Currently `ToDo` is bolded and highlighted blue and I would like to change `Hack` to be bold but highlighted red. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several extensions for Visual Studio that provide enhanced comments. See for example [Remarker](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/32af9cb5-bb6e-4f02-97c6-a172c3ac5445).